# Availability of Woocommerce Session after checkout?

Tags: php, wordpress, session, woocommerce, orders

I'm currently using a Woocommerce session to save information that the user inputs on the cart page which affects a fee added to the transaction.

I need to be able to access this information right after the order has been completed to make necessary updates to the user's account.

I figured `woocommerce_thankyou` would be a good hook to use, but unfortunately the session only seems to be available half of the time.

Are there any better hooks to use where I could confirm that the purchase had been completed and the session information would be available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to **save that session data as custom order meta data**, to be able to use it afterwards (replace `my_key`, in the code below, with the correct session key):

```
// Add custom order meta data with temporary data from WC_Session
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'add_session_data_as_custom_order_meta_data', 10, 2 );
function add_session_data_as_custom_order_meta_data( $order, $data ) {
    if ( $session_data = WC()->session->get('my_key') ) {
         $order->update_meta_data( '_session_data', $session_data );
    }
}
```

Code goes on function.php file of your active child theme (or theme). Tested and works.

---

Then to access the data you will use th `WC_Data` method `get_meta()` on the `WC_Order` Object:

```
$session_data = $order->get_meta('_session_data');
```

Or also using `get_post_meta()` function from a defined **order Id**:

```
$session_data = get_post_meta( $order_id, '_session_data', true );
```

Comment: This answer seems incomplete.. What is the reason for that? What happens to the session after checkout? Is a new session created? How and where?

Comment: @Tofandel Sorry but this answer here is just answering the Op question and it is complete as it's not a tutorial… Now after checkout, once this session variable value is set as custom order meta data, you can remove it using `WC()->session->__unset('my_key');`